# Quzrtz scheduler with multiple cron schedules in a single trigger

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net

I am trying to create a windows service that executes twice a day.
and I was successfully able to create it using two triggers added to a single job.

```cs
var job = JobBuilder.Create<Job>().StoreDurably().WithIdentity("Report_Name", "Report_Group").Build();
            scheduler.AddJob(job, true);

            var trigger_1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                .WithIdentity("Report_Name_1", "Report_Group_A")
                                .StartNow()
                                .WithCronSchedule(string.Format("0 {0} {1} ? * *", Utility.Schedule_StartTime_1.Minute, Utility.Schedule_StartTime_1.Hour)) //0 Min hour
                                .ForJob(job)
                                .Build();

            var trigger_2 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                               .WithIdentity("Report_Name_2", "Report_Group_B")
                               .StartNow()
                               .WithCronSchedule(string.Format("0 {0} {1} ? * *", Utility.Schedule_StartTime_2.Minute, Utility.Schedule_StartTime_2.Hour)) //0 Min hour
                               .ForJob(job)
                               .Build();

            scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger_1);
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger_2);

            scheduler.Start();
```

Can I use a single trigger to add multiple cron schedules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the trigger can have only one schedule.

One of the main reason why this is done is to prevent a situation when it is not clear for scheduler how to resolve competition between 
conditions.

Imagine you have a job with 2 intersected schedules: let's say you want to run the job every 15 mins and every hour, and it takes up to 10 mins to execute it. In this case, you would need to specify how you want to handle scenarios, when

- a job is executing, but scheduler fires new execution.
- a job should be fired by both schedules

To allow handling such cases, the trigger has attributes like Priority and Misfire Instructions.